# Train BERT with CLI commands

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I have downloaded the HuggingFace BERT model from the transformer repository found [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) and would like to train the model on custom NER labels by using the run_ner.py script as it is referenced [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/task_summary.html) in the section "Named Entity Recognition".

I define model ("bert-base-german-cased"), data_dir ("Data/sentence_data.txt") and labels ("Data/labels.txt)" as defaults in the code.

Now I'm using this input for the command line:

```
python run_ner.py --output_dir="Models" --num_train_epochs=3 --logging_steps=100 --do_train --do_eval --do_predict
```

But all it does is telling me:

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-german-cased were not used when initializing BertForTokenClassification: ['cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.w
eight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertForTokenClassification from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPretraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertForTokenClassification from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some weights of BertForTokenClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-german-cased and are newly initialized: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

After that it just stops, not ending the script, but simply waiting.

Does anyone know what could be the problem here? Am I missing a parameter?

My sentence_data.txt in CoNLL format looks like this (small snippet):

```
Strafverfahren O
gegen O
; O
wegen O
Diebstahls O
hat O
das O
Amtsgericht Ort
Leipzig Ort
- O
Strafrichter O
```

And that's how I defined my labels in labels.txt:

```
"Date", "Delikt", "Strafe_Tatbestand", "Schadensbetrag", "Geständnis_ja", "Vorstrafe_ja", "Vorstrafe_nein", "Ort",
"Strafe_Gesamtfreiheitsstrafe_Dauer", "Strafe_Gesamtsatz_Dauer", "Strafe_Gesamtsatz_Betrag"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. It had to do with the CUDA driver not being compatible with the installed version of pytorch.

For anyone with Nvidia GPU encountering the same problem: going to the Nvidia control panel -> Help -> System Information -> Components, there is a setting called "NVCUDA.DLL" with a driver number in the names column. Choosing the corresponding CUDA version in the installation builder on pytorch.org should do the trick.

Also, there is a good Readme in the transformers repository explaining all steps to train the BERT model with CLI commands [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/token-classification/README.md).